# How to make a single window on Mac OS X sticky to every desktop space?

Tags: macos, window, osx-spaces

I'm trying to make a single terminal window appear on every space but the built in spaces only allow to configure this per application basis. This makes it more or less useless for terminals if you have multiple terminal windows on multiple spaces.

[DesktopManager](http://desktopmanager.berlios.de/) seams to have solved this for older versions of Mac OS X.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 3rd party software [Afloat](https://github.com/rwu823/afloat) can do this. See the [installation instructions:](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113093/how-does-one-install-afloat-on-os-10-8-mountain-lion).

> 1. Download the SIMBL [zip file](http://www.culater.net/dl/files/SIMBL-0.9.9.zip)
> 2. Unzip the file
> 3. Double-click/install SIMBL-0.9.9.pkg
> 4. Create SIMBL bundle dir: mkdir ~/Library/Application\ Support/SIMBL/Plugins/
> 5. Reboot
> 6. Install from the git repo:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/millenomi/afloat.git
$ cd afloat
$ xcodebuild -configuration Release install
  # verbose output trimmed, except for last line:
  ** INSTALL SUCCEEDED **
$ mv /tmp/Afloat.dst/Users/`whoami`/Library/Bundles/Afloat.bundle/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/SIMBL/Plugins/
```

[image: Screen Capture]

Comment: Works for me for the most part. The only bad thing is the lack of updates on that repo. The author has not been active for some time.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this is still working on macOS Ventura M1?

Comment: I haven’t used Afloat in over 8 years. I would be surprised if this is still a correct or relevant answer…

Answer (score 37):

Not obvious but built into MacOS.

Right click on the application icon in the dock -> options -> All Desktops

Comment: This should be the correct answer of the question.

Comment: It works! But I tried to do that with multiple Chrome windows and mac shows all browser windows on all desktops. Is it a way to stick separate window of application? Thanks!

Comment: This works in many cases, but the OP explicitly said "single window", not all windows of an application

Comment: This answers the wrong question.