# Is there any way to force one Window of an Application to appear on all Spaces?

Tags: macos, osx-spaces

I'll sometimes have one window from an application that I need to access from all of my Spaces. Often this is a terminal or a specific chat window. Is there anyway I can force the one window to appear on all Spaces without having the entire application?

Edit: Forcing the entire application onto every space is not what I'm looking for. I only want one window of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not possible.**

There's no preference (even hidden, e.g. through [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com/)) for it. Hyperspaces (third party software) does not allow it. And it's exotic enough as requirement (and configuration would be nightmarish anyway) that I'm confident it doesn't exist.

As a workaround, you can move that window with you as you change spaces. [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) offers a few related keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks. That is sadly what I figured. I hoped there was a work around. As a temp solution I've used http://tomayko.com/writings/first-class-terminal-apps to build one off apps for the terminal windows I need on every desktop.

Answer (score 1):

At least for Terminal, I suggest using the excellent (free) "Visor" Plug-In that can be found here: http://visor.binaryage.com/ 
Visor gives you a dashboard-like Terminal window that you can invoke via a shortcut, not depending on which space you are in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible through the third party application [afloat](https://github.com/rwu823/afloat). See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/118813/129989) to the same question for details on installation and usage.