# Trying to compile afloat using xcode on OSX 10.9.4 - garbage collection is no longer supported

Tags: macos, xcode, afloat

I was following the instructions on [making a single window sticky with afloat](https://superuser.com/questions/118811/how-to-make-a-single-window-on-mac-os-x-sticky-to-every-desktop-space/921428#921428)

Here are the instructions in from the post:

```
 Download the SIMBL zip file
 Unzip the file
 Double-click/install SIMBL-0.9.9.pkg
 Create SIMBL bundle dir: mkdir ~/Library/Application\ Support/SIMBL/Plugins/
 Reboot
 Install from the git repo:

$ git clone https://github.com/millenomi/afloat.git
$ cd afloat
$ xcodebuild -configuration Release install
  # verbose output trimmed, except for last line:
  ** INSTALL SUCCEEDED **
$ mv /tmp/Afloat.dst/Users/`whoami`/Library/Bundles/Afloat.bundle/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/SIMBL/Plugins/
```

I followed the instructions to the t, and it didn't didn't work for me.

After installing xcode 6.0.1 on OS 10.9.4 and running xcodebuild -configuration Release install I received a bunch of error messages.

Here's the type of dump I received after each file, along with the output at the end of the process:

```
`error: garbage collection is no longer supported

** INSTALL FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/Afloat.build/Release/Afloat.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Afloat.o Afloat.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/Afloat.build/Release/Afloat.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AfloatStorage.o AfloatStorage.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/Afloat.build/Release/Afloat.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AfloatPanel.o AfloatPanel.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/Afloat.build/Release/Afloat.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AfloatPanelController.o AfloatPanelController.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(4 failures)
```

Did I download a version that's incompatible with OSX 10.9.4 Maverick? What's going wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

Try `xcodebuild` with `GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_GC=unsupported` to enable (now unsupported) garbage collection.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) could be improved by explaining how this might solve the OP's question.  Thanks for contributing.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.